# Angular Unit Test Component with Store dispatch action

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, ngrx

I have a component that has the following function:

```
onClearSearch() {
  this.store$.dispatch(some action);
}
```

Trying to unit test the component and trigger the store dispatch is not working. My component test looks like this:

```
let store: MockStore<State>;

beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestModule({
    ...
    providers: [
      SearchStoreEffects,
      provideMockActions(() => actions$),
      provideMockStore({initialState, selectors: [...]})
    ],
    ...
  }).compileComponents();

  ...
  store = TestBed.inject(MockStore);
  fixture.detectChanges();
}));

it('should clear search value', () => {
  const storeSpy = spyOn(store, 'dispatch').and.callThrough();
  component.onClearSearch();
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(storeSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

The test always fails with test has been called zero times. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I wrap the it assertion in fakeAsync, then call tick after component.onClearSearch();, it works

Answer (score 7):

You need to spy on the component instance

```typescript
it('should clear search value', () => {
  const storeSpy = spyOn(component.store$, 'dispatch').and.callThrough();
  component.onClearSearch();
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(storeSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Comment: What is the Error Message?

Comment: Same thing, "Expected spy dispatch to have been called once. It was called 0 times."

Comment: If I wrap the it assertion in fakeAsync, then call tick after component.onClearSearch();, it works

Comment: If you don't want to fix it to expect the number of times it was called... you can just use `expect(storeSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();`.